# How to get ID from site url in view page

Tags: php, html, database, codeigniter, adminlte

```
http://localhost/cisbeadmin/index.php/conuser/edituser/.$row->$id_pegawai
```

How can I get id from site url in CodeIgniter?
This is my code in view page:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('conuser/edituser/.$row->$id_pegawai'); ?>  "> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to get in view directly. You should get it in controller's method. In your case method name is **edituser**

Here is a way how you can get the id from url:

```
// Make sure your segment possition is correct and place few lines of code in starting of your method edituser()
$id = $this->uri->segment(3)) != '' && is_numeric($this->uri->segment(3)) && $this->uri->segment(3) > 0 ? $this->uri->segment(3) : false;

// After getting $id check if it is false or having value in it
if($id == false){
// If URL does not having id then it should show 404 error which is done by below line
   show_404();
}

// Pass $id value for view file same as we pass other values.
```

Hope I explained in detail. Let me know if you have any issue with that.

Answer (score 0):

> Replace code with this

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('conuser/edituser/'.$row->$id_pegawai); ?>  "> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

and after you can get id in your view as per below code

```
$id_pegawai = $this->uri->segment(2);
```